# Magento Custom module recognised in Admin Panel but not in store

Tags: php, magento, module

Ive made a custom module in magento. The Admin panel recognises it but not the store.. Ive checked many posts and sources but nothing solves my problem

Code In the app/etc/modules/Firstmagetest_All.xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
  <config>
  <modules>
    <Firstmagetest_Test>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
     </Firstmagetest_Test>
   </modules>
</config>
```

Code in app/code/local/FirstMageTest/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Firstmagetest_Test>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Firstmagetest_Test>
 </modules>
 <frontend>
   <routers>
      <firstmage_test>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Firstmagetest_Test</module>
             <frontName>test</frontName>
          </args>
       </firstmage_test>
   </routers>
  </frontend>
 </config>
```

[html]

Code in app/code/local/FirstMageTest/Test/controllers/IndexController.php

```
    <?php

class Firstmagetest_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function indexAction ()
{  
 echo 'test index';
 }
public function mamethodeAction ()
{
 echo 'test mymethod';
 }

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: So, which URL did you try to access it with, kind of vital information. Without testing it looks like www.yourdomain.com/test/index would do it?

Comment: I tried all these http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/test ,                             http://127.0.0.1/magento/test/index/  ,                                                 http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/test/index/index,

Comment: I even tried enabling the Add Store Code to Urls in the store->config->web->url . Yet it doesnt work. Disabled cache since the begnning. changed file permissions. Everything, yet it doesnt work. Im woring on Apache on Ubuntu...The module shows in store->advanced->enable module but not on the store front

Comment: Did you clear all caches, like config, fullpage cache and block cache?

Comment: Yes I have .I have disabled all cache, I had  flushed cache, refreshed cache before executing the module, yet it doesnt work.